# Is there any API in Linux to get the full language name from the locale?

Tags: c, linux, windows, locale

I want to get the complete language name from the locale in Linux. For example, in Windows, there is one API [GetLocaleInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getlocaleinfoex) we can use, it will return "English" for locale "en-US".

```
wchar_t buffer[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
GetLocaleInfoEx(L"en-US", LOCALE_SENGLISHLANGUAGENAME,
            (LPWSTR)buffer, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH)
```

This will fill the *buffer* with "English". Is there anything similar in Linux?

Comment: you should probably pass just `buffer` not `&buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
nl_langinfo(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE)
```

from

```
#include <langinfo.h>
```

if locale is not set, you can set it with

```
s = getenv("LANG");
setlocale(LC_ALL, s);
```

Comment: Normally the locale is initialized to the default via `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`. The equivalent of the thread-safe `GetLocaleInfoEx` call in the question would use a new `locale_t`, e.g.: `loc = newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK, "en_US.UTF-8", NULL);` `if (loc) {language = strdup(nl_langinfo_l(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE, loc)); freelocale(loc);}`. I changed it to use UTF-8 since just "en_US" isn't a commonly set locale alias. This differs significantly from Windows "<language>-<Script>-<REGION>\_<sort order>" locale names, which do not include an encoding and only require the "<language>" tag.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the other answers, I thought of concluding it here.

```
   #include <langinfo.h>
   #include <locale.h> // for LC_ALL_MASK flag, freelocale(), and newlocale() functions.
```

Access locale information from the system locale.

```
   char *nl_langinfo(nl_item item);
```

Access locale information from the *locale* given as a parameter.

```
   char *nl_langinfo_l(nl_item item, locale_t locale);
```

Use of *GetLocaleInfoEx* in the given example equivalent to the following on Linux.

```
locale_t loc = newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK, "en_US.UTF-8", NULL); 
if (loc) {
    language = strdup(nl_langinfo_l(_NL_IDENTIFICATION_LANGUAGE, loc));
    freelocale(loc);
   }
```

Refer to [nl_langinfo](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html) for more details.